# $script_filename causes error in nginx config

Tags: php, nginx

I'm working with a rather old php scripts which advises to put this directive in nginx configs

```
location / {
  if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
}
```

But this causes error on my `nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`

```
Sep 14 11:19:22 pc5 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 14 11:19:22 pc5 nginx[12497]: nginx: [emerg] unknown "script_filename" variable
Sep 14 11:19:22 pc5 nginx[12497]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 14 11:19:22 pc5 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 14 11:19:22 pc5 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 11:19:22 pc5 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy 
~
```

Here is my complete site configuration (runing on localhost)

```
server {
        listen 8000;
        root /var/www/myapp;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        #server_name example.com;
        autoindex off;
 

        location / {
          if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
           }
        }



        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

If I remove that directive many of the paths are not accessible and I get 404 instead.

As you can see below in my `fastcgi.conf I have no` $script_filename` parameter:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

And `fastcgi-php.conf`  :

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: There is no `$script_filename` on that file either. So how is it supposed to help?

Comment: That advice is nonsense. Try: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args; }`